# Emulator in Wifi is not getting connected when I am using LAN

Tags: android

System configuration 
1) 3 DNS which are displaying in my system.
2) 2 Proxy are configured in my system : a) Web Server proxy : port 80 b) Secure Web Server proxy port : 8080.

Approaches tried to connect wifi are :
1) Android emulator -> Extended Controls -> Settings -> Proxy -> 80 (I am not able to get the expected Wifi connected)

2) With the steps mentioned in the following site : https://medium.com/@indaniram/run-android-emulator-with-proxy-configurations-6586ecb5461d

Android Emulator -> Settings -> Network & Internet -> Mobile network -> Advanced -> Access Point Names : Have added New APN with the configuration webproxy.ssmb.com:8080 ; proxy : provided system IP address ; Tried port 8080 & also port 80 along with username & password. (I am not able to get the Wifi connected in my emulator)

3) Using command line also i tried to launch emulator and tried to verify the Wifi is connected, but no change in Wifi : emulator -avd emulatorname -dns-server systemdns

4) Using command line tried the below command too : emulator -avd emulatorname -dns-server 8.8.8.8

Can someone help on any other possible method of getting connected with my LAN.

Note : I am able to connect Android Emulator Wifi Settings via my Airtel Wifi Connection.